# Angular making input field null on validation failure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a member registration form where he enters his membership card number. The membership card number is a 19 digit number which starts with 6 4's and then followed by 13 digits.Now the user has the option to enter either last 13 digits alone or he can even enter the complete 19 digits. When he enters complete 19 digits on the blur event i trim the 1st 6 digits which leaves the last 13 digits. My code works fine for all scenarios but something weird happens when error happens in 1 particular scenario.

Working Scenarios are

- If the user types anything less then 13 digits or more then 19 digits i have a regex which validates the user input and shows the error message.
- If the user just types 13 digits, its fine
- If user types perfect 19 digits but his starting 6 digits are not 4's then error is diplayed.

Failed Scenario

- But when user types any digit >13 and <19  error message is triggered but my input field becomes empty, i.e. whatever user has typed just vanishes. **Is this angular library issue**

Please find the code below-

HTML

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.CardNumber" ng-blur="trimCardNumber()" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{13,19}$/" name="CardNumber">
```

Controller.JS

```
    $scope.trimCardNumber = function () {
    if (($scope.user.CardNumber).indexOf("444444") > -1) {
        $scope.user.CardNumber = ($scope.user.CardNumber).replace("444444", "");
        $scope._ServerForm.CardNumber.$invalid = false;
        return true;
    }
    else if ($scope.user.CardNumber.length != 13) {
        $scope._ServerForm.CardNumber.$invalid = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope._ServerForm.CardNumber.$invalid = false;
    }
}
```

I have created a JS fiddle for the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/achyut/x69hZ/1/

Steps to reproduce -

- Type 444444123456789012 and blur to see the issue

Comment: Is it possible somewhere in your code you reinitialize the model of user.CardNumber?

Comment: Failed scenario only happens when the first digits are 4's right?

Comment: @AlexanderNenkov - Inside the Trim function i am reassigning the model the trimed value

Comment: @Bertrand - The issue happens after the trim has happened and the regex has failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is discussed in the following thread

[input not showing invalid model values](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1412)

You can create your custom directive and validate it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of the way the digest cycle works.

When blur occurs trimCardNumber() removes the six 4's from the input.

```
$scope.user.CardNumber = $scope.user.CardNumber.replace("444444", "");
```

Because something changed during the digest cycle it becomes dirty and so a second round is triggered. In the second round the input now has less digits and this is causing the regex to invalidate it and clean the user.CardNumber model.

For example this card number (with 19 digits) will fail: 4444441111111111111 because after removing the 4's it will be invalidated by the regex.

if you change the regex to accept 12 to 19 the number above will work but a 18 numbers long would also fail.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/riku/1/edit)

I think the solution is to move the regex inside trimCardNumber(), or even better, you could create a [custom validation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) for the input.

Comment: 1 doubt - You said the regex invalidates the input tag and CLEAN the user.CardNumber Model. Exactly this is my question. Is this expected behaviour from Angular JS to clean the model on regex failure. Then it should also do the same when i just type 2 digits and blurs out. In this scenario also regex is failing

Comment: It cleans the model and because of the two-way binding the input is also cleared (again, because the dirty check). Check this [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/weyi/1/edit). I have set a $watcher on the user, start with a valid card number and watch your console. If the regex is valid the user receives the input's value, put a letter in the card number (so regex invalidates it) and the model will get cleared.

Comment: as mentioned by @Sai this is a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1412